# How does follow from a proof of a theorem that the theorem is correct?

Tags: logic, foundations, proof-theory

This question seems to me to be the foundation of the concept of a mathematical proof. If we have proved a statement we automatically conclude that the statement is correct. But why can we do this? Is there some sort of "proof" that this works? Or do we need to assume that our set of axioms are not contradictory?

Since I haven't learned any mathematical logic, I don't know how to think about questions like this. Furthermore it seems to me that this question can only be answered rigorously if first is defined what a proof actually is and then showed that if we have a proof of a statement – satisfying the definition of a proof – that then the statement is true.

Comment: By definition, a proof of a theorem shows that a theorem is an implication of our axioms, which is what we define to be "correct".

Comment: Ok, but this seems a bit too trivial to me, because it appears to me that a theorem being true or false is a priori independent of having a proof or not. So I am not satisfied by simply defininig a theorem as correct by just having a proof.

Comment: In a mathematical sense, any theorem that is correct has a proof, and any theorem that has a proof is correct. They aren't independent. Sure, we may not have found a proof yet, but if one exists, then the theorem is correct.

Comment: You are implicitely saying that truth is absolute and independent of any axiomatic, you also need to define how you manage the values True and False, etc which is basically what you would do in a logic course.

Comment: @TreFox By Gödels incomletness theorem (-> Wikipedia) it is not the case that every true statement has a proof. (This is the only locigal statement I know, but I can't state it formally).

Comment: @mathma Yes, but the question still stands

Comment: @ConstantinK What I mean is that as TreFox said, a statement is by definition a theorem if it can be (logically) derived from your set of axioms. This logic has to be also defined. The truthness or falseness of something is not absolute. I could make up my arbitrary set of axioms without even caring about consistency and I can make any statement true or false or both.

Comment: @ConstantinK I mean what you call proof is these series of manipulations valid according to your logic. And it works and we accept it because it gets you from point A to point B always according to your definition truth. Maybe I don't care about having contradictions at all, so I suppose a priori you don't need to exclude them.

Comment: @ConstantinK I think you may like the "What the Tortoise said to Achilles" story by Lewis Carroll

Answer (score 5):

We need to assume more than just that the axioms are not contradictory.  It is easy to see that if we prove a theorem in a way that satisfies the following two assumptions, the theorem must be true:

1. Each of the axioms we use in the proof is true
2. Each of the inference rules we use in the proof produces (only) true statements when applied to true statements

The challenge is how to justify (1) and (2). If we try to "prove" formally that our axioms are true, we will have to prove that the axioms we use for *that* proof are true, and so on, in an unending loop.

So, instead, we typically "perceive" facts (1) and (2), in some informal way, rather than proving them mathematically.  So, for example, the majority of mathematicians believe that our usual rules of proof satisfy property (2), and believe that the axioms they typically work with satisfy property (1). But they don't *prove* this in the same way as a mathematical theorem.

If we only assume our axioms are not contradictory, that does not mean they have to satisfy property (1). It is possible to have consistent axioms that are, nevertheless, false.

Property (2) is called "soundness" in mathematical logic, and it is easier to justify than property (1), although it still takes some work. The rules of inference, unlike the axioms we use, are context neutral, so we only have to verify property (2) once, whereas we have to check property (1) again for each new set of axioms.

In some cases, there are heuristic arguments that help to show why a particular set of axioms should be "true". Of course, some people accept these arguments more than others do. For example, it is often argued that the Peano axioms are true because, in our usual understanding of the natural numbers, the natural numbers satisfy all the Peano axioms. Similarly, there is a more intricate argument that tries to justify that the ZFC axioms for set theory are true, based on a particular understanding of what sets are.